# Define multiple functions at once

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to declare 26 functions, for the letters a to z, like so:

```js
foo.a = function() {
 // code
}

foo.b = function() {
 // code
}

foo.c = function() {
 // code
}
```

and so on. But this is very redundant and quite annoying, so I am wondering if there is an easier way of doing this.

Comment: It will be helpful to know what each of the functions will do in order to help you most effectively.. can you tell us what your intent is please?

Comment: What's the point of assigning the same function code to 26 different properties on the same object?  This makes no sense at all.  I am 100% sure there is a better way to solve whatever problem you're actually trying to solve.  In the future, tell us what the real problem is and we have a chance to offer you much better ways to solve it than the ways you've thought of so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can do it in a loop:

```
const foo = {}
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('').forEach((letter) => {
  foo[letter] = function () { /* code */ }
})
```

I wrote out the letters in the string for clarity, but there are other ways to generate strings of consecutive characters, such as using an array and String.fromCharCode.

This won't help you at all if the code in each function needs to be unique, since all you have to go on is what you have available, but if you wanted to, for example, make each function return its own letter, that would work.

```
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('').forEach((letter) => {
  foo[letter] = () => letter
})
```

Comment: Thanks! Will this work fine for non-static methods in a class?

Comment: It will. You can either do it in the class, for example in the constructor with `this[letter] = ...`, or you can do it outside of the class, using `SomeClass.prototype[letter] = ...` since classes are at least partially just syntax sugar for prototypes.